# How to make random.randit get new number, every time the game starts again

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

i have to make this GUESS THE NUMBER Gamme from 1-100 that will restart if user wants to play again,
the user can try to find the number  10 times.
But i  have a problem..
every time the user says "yes" to play again,the program will not change the random number,i try to find some solution but i didnt
here is the code

```
    import random

guesses = 0  # μετραει ποσες προσπαθειεςς εγιναν απο τον χρηστη
print("Hello,lets play a game...and try to find the number i have guess!!")
number = random.randint(1, 100)

**while guesses < 11:

    print('Please Guess a number from (1-100):')
    enter = input()
    enter = int(enter)

    guesses = guesses + 1

    if enter < number:
        print('This number you enter  is lower,please try again')

    if enter > number:
        print('This number you enter is higher,please try again')

    if enter == number:
        score = 10 - guesses
        score = str(score)
        guesses = str(guesses)

        print('Well Done, You found it! \nYor Score is' + score + '!')
        print('DO you want to play again;  yes/no:')

        out = input()
        if out == "no":
            break
        elif out == "yes":
            guesses = 0

    if guesses > 10:
        number = str(number)
        print("i'm sorry you lost, the number is  " + number)
```

print("Have a great time")**

Comment: How about after the user says yes, you set `number` to a new value?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to reset the `guesses`  inside the `elif out == "yes"` block, reset also the number. Try:

```
elif out == "yes":
    guesses = 0
    number = random.randint(1, 100)
```